# PYTHON SQLITE3 DELETE FROM LIST

Tags: function, tkinter, sql-delete, newforms

I want to delete data from selected in ListBox. I tried everything but it's not working. I tried in simple file. It worked. I wrote same code here but it's not working. I'm stuck since two days. Please help.

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox
import randevuEkleme as fRE
from tkcalendar import *


def randevularFormunuAc():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Randevu Listesi Formu")
    root.geometry("750x500")

    randevuListesi = Listbox(root, width=50, bg="yellow", selectmode=SINGLE)

    takvim = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", year=2020, month=5, day=22)
    takvim.grid(row=0, column=0)
    randevuListesi.grid(row=1, column=0)
    secilen = randevuListesi.curselection()

    def randevulariListele(): #OK!
        con = sqlite3.connect('veri2.db')
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM randevular")
        liste = c.fetchall()
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        randevuListesi.delete(first=0,last=END)
        for i in liste:
        randevuListesi.insert(END,i)

    con = sqlite3.connect('veri2.db')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM randevular")
    liste = c.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    for i in liste:
        randevuListesi.insert(END, i)

    def randevuSil():  
        con = sqlite3.connect('veri2.db')
        c = con.cursor()

        # Problem is HERE!!!   
        c.execute("DELETE FROM randevular WHERE rowid = (?)", (secilen[0] + 1,))
        
        # PROBLEMIS HERE!!!
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    btnListele = Button(root, text="Randevuları Listele",command=randevulariListele)
    btnRandevuEkle = Button(root,text="Randevu Ekle",command=fRE.randevuEklemeFormunuAc)
    btnRandevuSil = Button(root,text="Randevuyu Sil",command=randevuSil()) !!!!
    btnCikis = Button(root, text="Geri", command=root.quit)
    btnListele.grid(row=2,column=0)
    btnRandevuEkle.grid(row=2,column=1)
    btnRandevuSil.grid(row=2,column=2)
    btnCikis.grid(row=2,column=3)

    root.mainloop()
```

and error message is :

```py
File "C:\Users\kutla\PycharmProjects\fizyoOta1.0\randevularFormu.py", line 43, in randevuSil
c.execute("DELETE FROM randevular WHERE rowid = (?)", (secilen[0] + 1,))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: What does `print(secilen[0])` return? you have to also change `command=randevuSil()` to `command=randevuSil` for the button

Comment: It's for debug.  I just wanna see what's secilen[0]
It returns ()

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Just "()"
Nothing more

Comment: That is the problem right? it does not return anything, `c.execute("DELETE FROM randevular WHERE rowid = (?)", (secilen[0] + 1,))` will give error because `secilen[0]` is empty or something

Comment: It's empty because `secilen` is set at the beginning, before the user has had a chance to set anything, and because `randevuSil()` is also called at the beginning, before the user has had a chance to set anything.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities on a quick read:

- The line `secilen = randevuListesi.curselection()` probably needs to be in `randevuSil()` rather than as part of the setup.
- When setting up the button, the `()` should be omitted in the `command=`:

  ```
  btnRandevuSil = Button(root,text="Randevuyu Sil",command=randevuSil)
  ```

  Otherwise the function will be called as part of setup (when nothing has been selected yet) rather than when the button is clicked.

Comment: "The line secilen = randevuListesi.curselection() probably needs to be in randevuSil() rather than as part of the setup."
In begining, It was that before. I thought, if I list data first, It won't be a problem. But it didn't worked.

btnRandevuSil = Button(root,text="Randevuyu Sil",command=randevuSil())
But it didn't worked

Comment: You need to fix both problems.